# how to search multiple information with condition from multiple files in python

Tags: python, file, search

I am trying to search 'TestTime' and 'Runtime ' in all .output file in a directory and all subfolders, and I only need Runtime if I found 'Test Time ' in that file , below is my code :

```
import os
import os.path
import csv
path = '/user/data/2022/test'
foutput = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.OUTPUT')]
fout = open('Res', 'w')
fieldnames =['Design', 'Run time', 'Test Time']
writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in [f for f in files if f.endswith(".OUTPUT")]:            
        with open(os.path.join(root,file), 'r') as fin:
            lines = fin.readline()
            for line in lines:
                flag = 0 
                if(line.find('Test time')):
                    flag =1 #  set a flag when I got TestTime 
                    TestTime = line.split()# save my test time data, and ask keep reading from current file to search 'Run time'                          
                    continue
                if(line.find('phys_opt_design: Time (s):') and flag == 1):                                
                    RunTime = line.split(":")
                    writer.writerow({'Design': fin.name, 'Test time': TestTime[5], 'Run time':RunTime[0] }) 




fin.close()
fout.close()
```

but it is not working as expected and only ready from one file , can anyone help ?

Comment: `fin.readline()` will read a single line, not *lines*

Comment: thanks ! I made it work by using readlines and deal with the index .      like below:       lines = fin.readlines()
            for i in range(0, len(lines)):

Answer (score 0):

For this code to work, use re module, where you can write regular expression to match the information you are looking for.

```
#sample
import re
pattern = re.compile(line)
match = pattern.find('Test time')
```

This should work